# Is there an SVN benchmark?

Tags: svn

We want to do some performance optimizations on our local SVN server (like moving to a better server, adding an SSD, etc...)

Is there some benchmark I could use to see if these modifications actually help performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is one (published by CollabNet) -- https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/projects/csvn/

In SVN server 1.8.0 fsfs-stats and svn-bench were introduced.  The CollabNet install does not include them at the moment.

Comment: And another one (designed for a different purpose) is at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/dev/benchmarks/suite1 (results are published at http://svn-qavm.apache.org/charts/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that benchmarking out disk in this case would make sense ... should be directly proportional with SVN performance.

I prefer Sisoftware Sandra but there are plenty of tools out there.