# What is the storage mechanism behind Git Large File Storage?

Tags: git, github

Github recently introduced a [extension](https://github.com/blog/1986-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs) to git for storing large files in a different way. What exactly they mean by ***extension replaces large files with text pointers inside Git*** ?

Comment: The link you cite explains it pretty thoroughly.  What part don't you understand?

Comment: @AndrewC Italic bold text. Difference between text pointers and binary data of file.

Comment: It's just the difference between having c:\very_large_video.wmv eating up 5Gb on your hard drive versus storing the string http://url/to/very_large_video.wmv and having it stored somewhere else

Comment: Do you mean file data will not be in source control?

Comment: `while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see in the [git-lfs sources](https://github.com/github/git-lfs) how a ["text pointer" is defined](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/a0d38938509ffe258928f3fb432c1f5589fdc9c8/pointer/pointer.go#L31-L36):

```
type Pointer struct {
    Version string
    Oid     string
    Size    int64
    OidType string
}
```

The [smudge](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/a0d38938509ffe258928f3fb432c1f5589fdc9c8/pointer/smudge.go) and [clean](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/a0d38938509ffe258928f3fb432c1f5589fdc9c8/pointer/clean.go) sources means `git-lfs` can use a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)** in order to:

- download the actual files on checkout
- store them in their external source on commit.

See [the pointer specs](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/a0d38938509ffe258928f3fb432c1f5589fdc9c8/docs/spec.md):

> The core Git LFS idea is that **instead of writing large blobs to a Git repository, only a pointer file is written**.

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:4d7a214614ab2935c943f9e0ff69d22eadbb8f32b1258daaa5e2ca24d17e2393
size 12345
(ending \n)
```

> Git LFS needs a URL endpoint to talk to a remote server.
>   A Git repository can have different Git LFS endpoints for different remotes.

The actual file is upload to or downloaded from a server which respect the [Git-LFS API](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/a0d38938509ffe258928f3fb432c1f5589fdc9c8/docs/api.md).

This is confirmed by the [`git-lfs` man page](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/a0d38938509ffe258928f3fb432c1f5589fdc9c8/docs/man/git-lfs.1.ronn), which mentions:

> The actual file gets pushed to a **[Git LFS API](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/a0d38938509ffe258928f3fb432c1f5589fdc9c8/docs/api.md)**

You need a Git server which implements that API in order to support for uploading and downloading binary content.

---

Regarding the content filter driver (which exists in Git for a long time, well before lfs, and is used here by lfs to add this "large file management" feature), this is where the bulk of the work happens:

> The **smudge filter** runs as files are being checked out from the Git repository to the working directory.
>   Git sends the content of the Git blob as STDIN, and expects the content to write to the working directory as STDOUT.
>
> Read 100 bytes.
>
> - If the content is ASCII and matches the pointer file format:
>     Look for the file in .git/lfs/objects/{OID}.
> - If it's not there, download it from the server.
>     Read its contents to STDOUT
> - Otherwise, simply pass the STDIN out through STDOUT.
>
> The **clean filter** runs as files are added to repositories.
>   Git sends the content of the file being added as STDIN, and expects the content to write to Git as STDOUT.
>
> - Stream binary content from STDIN to a temp file, while calculating its SHA-256 signature.
> - Check for the file at `.git/lfs/objects/{OID}`.
> - If it does not exist:
>
>   - Queue the OID to be uploaded.
>   - Move the temp file to `.git/lfs/objects/{OID}`.
> - Delete the temp file.
> - Write the pointer file to STDOUT.

---

Git 2.11 (Nov. 2016) has a commit detailing even more how this works: [commit edcc858](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edcc85814c87ebd7f3b1b7d3979fac3dfb84d308), helped by Martin-Louis Bright and signed-off by: Lars Schneider.

> ### `convert`: add `filter.<driver>.process` option
>
> Git's clean/smudge mechanism invokes an external filter process for
>   every single blob that is affected by a filter. If Git filters a lot of
>   blobs then the startup time of the external filter processes can become
>   a significant part of the overall Git execution time.
>
> In a preliminary performance test this developer used a clean/smudge
>   filter written in golang to filter 12,000 files. This process took 364s
>   with the existing filter mechanism and 5s with the new mechanism. See
>   details here: [git-lfs/git-lfs#1382](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/1382)
>
> **This patch adds the `filter.<driver>.process` string option which, if
>   used, keeps the external filter process running and processes all blobs
>   with the packet format (`pkt-line`) based protocol over standard input and
>   standard output**.
>   [The full protocol is explained in detail in `Documentation/gitattributes.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/edcc85814c87ebd7f3b1b7d3979fac3dfb84d308/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L384-L526).
>
> A few key decisions:
>
> - The long running filter process is referred to as filter protocol
>     version 2 because the existing single shot filter invocation is
>     considered version 1.
> - Git sends a welcome message and expects a response right after the
>     external filter process has started. This ensures that Git will not
>     hang if a version 1 filter is incorrectly used with the
>     `filter.<driver>.process` option for version 2 filters. In addition,
>     Git can detect this kind of error and warn the user.
> - The status of a filter operation (e.g. "success" or "error) is set
>     before the actual response and (if necessary!) re-set after the
>     response. The advantage of this two step status response is that if
>     the filter detects an error early, then the filter can communicate
>     this and Git does not even need to create structures to read the
>     response.
> - All status responses are pkt-line lists terminated with a flush
>     packet. This allows us to send other status fields with the same
>     protocol in the future.

This has for consequence a warning set in Git 2.12 (Q1 2017)

See [commit 7eeda8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7eeda8b8214bfd171f9ed1265ecc5bfa1d06c607) (18 Dec 2016), and [commit c6b0831](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6b0831c9c1718b552872953b4949cef7d4726fe) (03 Dec 2016) by [Lars Schneider (`larsxschneider`)](https://github.com/larsxschneider).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 08721a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08721a056b0370e0de002162dfc5578548c0c116), 27 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### `docs`: warn about possible '`=`' in clean/smudge filter process values
>
> A pathname value in a clean/smudge filter process "`key=value`" pair can
>   contain the '`=`' character (introduced in [edcc858](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edcc85814c87ebd7f3b1b7d3979fac3dfb84d308)).
>   Make the user aware of this issue in the docs, add a corresponding test case, and fix the issue in filter process value parser of the example implementation in `contrib`.

Comment: For people like me who are struggling to understand the basic ideas behind this comprehensive answer, a 'smudge' command runs when code is checked out from a repository; and a 'clean' command runs in the opposite direction, i.e. when code is committed.  I think of them as being a bit like hooks that can be used to insert actions into the commit or checkout workflow.  As @VonC explains, git-lfs uses them to store a pointer instead of a large file in the commit step.  I found the link to git attribute filter drivers particularly useful: (http://schacon.github.io/git/gitattributes.html.

Comment: @John Exactly. You can see an example of smudge hook here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64710964/6309. And clean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30945624/6309