# EGit - Committing java documentation

Tags: java, eclipse, git, javadoc, egit

I'm using EGit with GitHub.

When I commit and push the code with EGit to GitHub it shows only the code without the javadoc.
Is there a preference in EGit to turn this off? (to export all of the code)

In Eclipse:

[image: http://www.xlp-now.de/webspace/stackoverflow/commitJavaDoc/IconLoaderEclipse.png]

In GitHub:

[image: http://www.xlp-now.de/webspace/stackoverflow/commitJavaDoc/IconLoaderGitHub.png]

Comment: Give more details how you are moving code from egit to github what commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a preference in egit to turn this off? (to export all of the code)

No: unless you have a [clean content filer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30945624/6309) (in a `.gitattributes` files), and text file will be pushed in its entirety to GitHub.

The [OP Cedric van den Berg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910813/cedric-van-den-berg) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814791/egit-committing-java-documentation/39814917?noredirect=1#comment67163940_39814917) solving the issue with the filters:

```
$ git config --global filter.indent.clean indent
$ git config --global filter.indent.smudge cat
```

Comment: It was very difficult to find that filter but that problem is solved when have the git shell, go into the repository and type in: 
$ git config --global filter.indent.clean indent,
$ git config --global filter.indent.smudge cat

Comment: @CedricvandenBerg Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @CedricvandenBerg don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer