# Is it bad to store Apache conf files on github?

Tags: apache, github, configuration

I'm working on a project that when deployed will need to modify an existing Apache config. Currently the conf files are are not included in the github repository, I would like to add them which would let me make the changes required in the branch I'm working on.

The current maintainer and I are unsure if including these files is a security risk? What is considered best practice in this regard?

Comment: Public site + publc GitHub == public sees everything == bad IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is better is to store an `httpd.conf.tpl` *template* file with placeholder values in it.

That allows you to *generate* the right httpd.conf file locally, and to do so automatically on `git clone`/`git checkout`.

The generation script will:

- search the right values for any sensitive data from an external secure referential (like a vault)
- replace the placeholder value in `httpd.conf.tpl` to generate the right `httpd.conf` (that can be ignored by Git)

For that, do register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script will generate (automatically, on `git checkout` or `git switch`) the actual `httpd.conf` file as mentioned above.
Again, the generated actual `httpd.conf` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".