# How does Git determine the "remote I normally pull from" to decide the behavior of push.default = simple?

Tags: git, configuration, push, default

Starting with Git version 2.0, the default value for the `push.default` config option if not specified in the user's config, is `simple`.

According to the documentation, this means:

> in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch's name is different from the
> local one.
>
> When pushing to **a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from,** work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for
> beginners.

In playing around with "git push" edge cases while writing training materials, I found a surprising ramification of the configuration options:

If you are on a branch that has no upstream configured, and you run `git push my-remote` when you have two remotes, in some cases you will get the error:

```
fatal: The current branch my-branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream my-remote my-branch
```

And in other cases, the push will succeed and will create the new branch on the remote, and the remote-tracking branch to go along with it (but not configure the remote branch as upstream).

After some extreme confusion about the inconsistency and some digging through the documentation, I finally realized that the `upstream` config option for `push.default` (which `simple` *sometimes* acts like) will only push to the *upstream* branch, and so will fail if no upstream is configured, whereas the `current` config option (which `simple` also *sometimes* acts like) will work regardless of whether an upstream is configured or not.

The crux of the matter, then, is whether Git is working as `current` or as `upstream` for a particular push when the `simple` option is selected (or left blank).  The documentation only says that it works as `current` "when pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from."  **So, how does it determine that?**

I've checked some obvious things like which remotes do I have remote-tracking branches for, but the results still seem inconsistent between my two test repos.  I've even tried adding a new empty repo as a remote for my repo that's giving me the error message, and trying to push to that, but I get the same error.  Unfortunately, I've been playing with fetching and pushing in these test repos so much today that it's hard to pin down what the difference is.

But this question **isn't about** my specific repos or why they're behaving inconsistently; that's just an attempt to reverse engineer the answer to this question, which the documentation seems to leave unclear.

Answers that refer to the documentation would be greatly appreciated (I'm not sure the answer can be found there); answers that refer to Git source code are fine also, but I'm not fully fluent reading C so an explanation would be helpful.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [see in `t5528-push-default.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/228f53135a4a41a37b6be8e4d6e2b6153db4a8ed/t/t5528-push-default.sh#L94-L194) all the tested use-cases with [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) using a [push policy '`simple`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault)'

In particular:

```sh
test_expect_success 'push to existing branch, with no upstream configured' '
    test_config branch.master.remote repo1 &&
    git checkout master &&
    test_push_failure simple &&
    test_push_failure upstream
'

test_expect_success 'push to existing branch, upstream configured with same name' '
    test_config branch.master.remote repo1 &&
    test_config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master &&
    git checkout master &&
    test_commit six &&
    test_push_success upstream master &&
    test_commit seven &&
    test_push_success simple master
'

test_expect_success 'push to existing branch, upstream configured with different name' '
    test_config branch.master.remote repo1 &&
    test_config branch.master.merge refs/heads/other-name &&
    git checkout master &&
    test_commit eight &&
    test_push_success upstream other-name &&
    test_commit nine &&
    test_push_failure simple &&
    git --git-dir=repo1 log -1 --format="%h %s" "other-name" >expect-other-name &&
    test_push_success current master &&
    git --git-dir=repo1 log -1 --format="%h %s" "other-name" >actual-other-name &&
    test_cmp expect-other-name actual-other-name
'
```

If your upstream branch is specified (`git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master`), a simple or upstream push policy will work.
Provided the branch name matches the upstream one.

> `upstream` - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called `@{upstream}`).
> This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).

> `simple` - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the local one.

If you think an edge-case is not covered by those tests, the new [git bugreport command](https://github.com/git/git/commit/238b439d69890980dafc5154895d425cb4cf4a5e) (Git 2.27+) can come in handy.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to see if I can narrow it down further, then.  Neither of these test repos has an upstream branch configured for "master."

Comment: But the example I mention, and the git config command I reference does set an upstream branch for master.

Comment: Right, I meant my own two test repos in which I observe differing behavior have neither one of them an upstream configured for master.  I'll have to figure out what is it that triggers the differing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The remote we normally pull from is determined on a per-branch basis using the configuration variable `branch.<branch-name>.remote`.
If no remote is configured, or if you are not on any branch, it defaults to `origin`.
Example:
Let's suppose we have two remotes origin and origin2.
For our branch master, we set as remote `origin2`: `git config branch.master.remote origin2`.
Suppose that `push.default` is set to `simple`.
Suppose also that no upstream is configured for `master`.
When we are on branch `master`, let's run `git push`. 
There is an error because we are in `simple` mode and pushing is blocked. 
However if we run `git push origin`, it works as current because we are pushing to a remote that is different from the remote we normally pull from, which is `origin2`.
Now let's unset the remote: `git config --unset branch.master.remote`.
In this case the remote defaults to `origin`, hence if we re-run the same push commands, pushing this time is blocked for `origin2` but not for `origin`.